# Android Game loop, Memory and animations

Tags: android, memory, game-loop

I'm new in Android and i'm developing the Insult Swordfighting of Monkey Island 1, but i'm facing some noob problems :)

This is my GameLoop:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {

private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

// desired fps
private final static int    MAX_FPS = 50;   
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;    
// the frame period
private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  


// Surface holder that can access the physical surface
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// The actual view that handles inputs
// and draws to the surface
private MainGamePanel gamePanel;    

// flag to hold game state 
private boolean running;
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    // initialise timing elements for stat gathering
    initTimingElements();

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;

        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }

            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}
```

First noob question:

Is it legit that the background or fixed images (like a finished animation frame) are rendered constantly? Is it a waste of memory?
I'd like to start with a cheap memory logic before to start with a major use of animations.

Second question:

In my render() function I call

```
canvas.drawBitmap(background, null,new Rect(0, 0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()), paint);
```

or

```
Rect dest = new Rect(this.getXpos(), getYpos(), getXpos() + (rclip.right - rclip.left),
            getYpos() + (rclip.bottom - rclip.top));
canvas.drawBitmap(tileSheet, rclip, dest, null);
```

Is it right to call all that "new"? GC cleans those after using them?